# How to check if a block is extended?

Tags: django-templates

To take an example of SO itself, the title can be set as

```
<title>{% block post_name %}{% block% } - StackOverflow</title>
```

However, if post_name is not defined, the title becomes `- StackOverflow` with the excess `-`

How can I test if a block is extended so that I can conditionally set the `-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to make the parent template behave differently based on which blocks a child template defines.  To get the desired output you'd have to remove the `-` from the parent template and add `-` at the end of the `post_name` block in each child template.

Alternatively, if you wanted to have the `- StackOverflow` suffix in some child templates but not others, you could move `StackOverflow` into the parent template's `post_name` block and then reference that text from within the child template using the `{{ block.super }}` variable.

In the parent template:

```
<title>{% block post_name %}StackOverflow{% block %}</title>
```

In the child template:

```
{% block post_name %}Title of post goes here - {{ block.super }}{% block %}
```